# Is CSS performance better for several class selectors or a single :not()?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

I am wondering what is better practice in terms of performance, if using several class selectors or a single one using [:not()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp).

As an example (this is an oversimplification):

```
div.caseB,
div.caseC,
div.caseD,
div.caseE,
div.caseF,
div.caseG
{ color: red; }
```

(where div will always have one class caseA...caseG).

Or:

```
div:not(.caseA)
{ color: red; }
```

Comment: Negligible. I can't see this having any measurable impact on performance unless you're talking about tens of thousands of classes. I would focus more on code maintenance, simplicity and readability.

Comment: ... although if you're talking about tens of thousands of classes, the answer is that a single :not() is much, much leaner on bandwidth. @Michael_B

Comment: @BoltClock, and in both cases, simpler, easier to read, and easier to maintain :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best case here will be to add a new class .red to give color red.

Using :not(caseA)is . Not practical. As if you have 100 clases, everything except .caseA will be red.

If you have classes caseA/B/C/..., they should be only create to distinguish one from another.

Remember [DRY](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-helper-classes-dry-scale-css/)

Otherwise if everything is red except for caseA, you can do.

```
body{color:red}
.caseA{color:green} // other color.
```